# FullCalendar and qTip. Help with description as array

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip

I have problem with load description. I'm getting answer via ajax this is JSON part information:

```
{"id":"","start":1282561200,"end":1282564800,"title":"admin admin","description":[["Alcatel-6850, ","Alcatel-6400, "]]}
```

This is code to rendering event:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content : event.description,
            position: {
                corner: {
                    tooltip: 'bottomLeft',
                    target: 'topRight'
                }
            },
            style   : {
                width: 200,
                padding: 5,
                //background: '#A2D959',
                color: 'black',
                textAlign: 'center',
                border: {
                    width: 2,
                    radius: 5,
                    color: '#A2D959'
                },
                tip: 'bottomLeft',
                name: 'blue'
            }
        });
```

How to load this description array to tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer:

```
content: (event.description.join(", ")),
```